# Error: Couldn't find preset "" relative to directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

I am unable to use es-15 with node.js I dont think that there is any problem with script as it was working before.

Package.json is below

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015, stage-2"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-graphql": "^0.7.1",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5"
  }
}
```

On running npm start, I get the error below,

```
> server@1.0.0 start /home/ansh/boo/server
> nodemon index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015, stage-2

[nodemon] 1.18.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node index.js --presets es2015, stage-2`
/home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:328
        throw e;
        ^

Error: Couldn't find preset "" relative to directory "/home/ansh/boo/server"
    at /home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at compile (/home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
    at loader (/home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/ansh/boo/server/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: could you try `--presets=es2015`

Comment: fixed it! It should be `es2015,stage-2` instead of `es2015, stage-2`